# How to add a template from another file in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm writing a web app using `phonegap` and `Ionic`. I want to write each HTML page in a different file but I cannot manage to do this. In `Ionic` API they show only the following example:

```
<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

Which is a HTML code written inside a `<script>` tags, in the `index.html` page.
I tried to create a different file with the name `home.html` for instance, and received the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file: path-to-the-file. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

My `js` is looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])


.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
// Set and define states
$stateProvider
    .state('/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```

})

and html page:

```
<ion-view title="home">
<ion-content>
   The content of the page 
  <a href="#/home">Register</a>
</ion-content>
```

I see the `index.html` page with the register link, but clicking it doesn't execute anything.
It seems like only when it is wrapped in a `<script>` tags it works.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the script tags. Ionic does this for you:

```
<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
```

And you can't use ui-router by loading index.html as the base state, as index should have the first ui-router html tag. You need to include  in index.html, and create some sort of menu file if you want to have a base/abstract state, such as the following:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
// Set and define states
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
    })
    .state('app.home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app");
```